# Is it Possible to Group files inside Mac App Resources Folder

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm developing a Mac Application with Xcode and Objective C, i'm also planning to use a C++ executable inside the App.

I want the C++ binary inside MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS folder and want to group the conf required for my C++ exe like

MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/conf/MyApp.conf

MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/conf/MyAppVer.conf

MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/db/populate.sql

Also the images i'm using for the App like logo.icns(App ICON),png's,etc , i want them grouped inside the Resources Folder under

MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/images

Is it possible to group the Resources Like this and access them in my app ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can have folders inside your Resources folder. Create your folders (images, conf, db, etc.) in the Finder and place your files in the appropriate folders. Add the folders to your project. When you add the files to your project, there will be two Folders radio buttons at the bottom the Open panel. Select the Create folder references for any added folders radio button.

[image]